# Could I test Production Certificate before submitting my app to appstore

Tags: ios

I tested remote push notification using developemnt certificate as explained in below tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

now, I need to submit my appstore to Appstore, but i'm not sure when do I need to change certificate to production certificate,

- if I change the certificate now, Is there away to test it before app get posted in appstore.
- or, maybe I could wait until it get posted in appstore and than, change certificate in server, but in this case, Apple most likely will reject the app, becouse it will not be fully funcational at the time of testing.

any advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by disturbing application as an ad hoc, production certificate is used.

according to apple documentation:

> "apps distributed via ad-hoc use the apple production push gateway
>   (gateway.push.apple.com), not the apple dev push gateway"

Comment: Did you test your push notifications with production certificates before submitting to app store ?